# What does the slang "cerote" mean?

Tags: definiciones, expresiones, coloquialismos, hispanoamérica

I know this is a slang expression from Central American people. I don't remember the context but it was something like:

> Eres un **cerote**! (from a pretty angry girl)

I'm pretty sure it doesn't mean I'm a big zero, or does it?

Comment: Although not a direct answer to your question, there is a popular mexican expression that includes "**cero**" in it. **Example**: > Eres un cero a la izquierda. Which means that you are worthless because zeros on the left, such as this example 01 = 1, don't count.

Comment: a pretty angry girl is ambiguous.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *Diccionario del español de Nicaragua* by Francisco Arellano Oviedo of the Academia Nicaragüense de la Lengua defines it as solid excrement, an incapable person, or a person of little social worth:

> **cerote.**
>   m. mals.
>
> Mierda sólida. *Arturo come maduro, cerote duro.* (dicho popular).
>
> || **2.** desp. Persona incapaz. *El que llegue por último es cerote de chancho.* (Dicho popular usado por los niños.)
>
> || **3.** desp. Persona de poca valía social. *--Enrique, me alegra verte, cómo vas a creer que esos cerotes me hayan descuidado la yegua.* J.E. Argüello, LHA. p. 146

Comment: So I am a "Mierda sólida" :(

Comment: What was the remark *Cerote" or "Cerrote"

Answer (score 11):

**Cerote** is the definition for a piece of shit, but if you are in Guatemala, for instance, **cerote** could be a friendly way to say that you did something wrong or impolite, for example:

> Cerote, esa era mi cerveza / Man, that was my beer

Also it could be used for a greeting in a close friendship

> ¿Qué hay cerote? ¿cómo vas? / What's up, dude?

If you want to denigrate someone

> Ese cerote es bien mula / That guy is really dumb

Also, can be used to express your admiration to someone

> Que cerote pa' jugar fut / You are so good in soccer

But if an unknown person come to you saying that, well, nobody will do that. If they really want to say something mean to you, they will use some other words like

> Cerote, hijo de la gran p....

Ok that one doesn't need explanation.

I'm Guatemalan, and that word is part of my daily life vocabulary. And by the way, we mostly all the time pronounce it like **serote**!

Answer (score 7):

From the point of view of Mexican Spanish:

"Eres un cerote" does mean you're a big zero, a nothing or worthless.

and

"Eres un cerrote" means you are a big turd or crap.

Comment: Same here in Spain about 'cerote'. Although not common at all, I think most people would understand that. And never heard of 'cerrote' with double R.

Answer (score 1):

A `cerote` is a pebble of shit, so only babies shit cerotes.

Answer (score 0):

Cerote es como decir:

> You are a shit